# Can't convert Symbol into String with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm newbie in ruby on rails, and i'm trying to use paperclip to drag and drop image. When i run my app, i have an error:

```
 Started POST "/uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-11 08:59:54 +0700
    Processing by UploadsController#create as JSON
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EXaUGMxPQt6otEUvPAd97IHEq61lYDmmHElxSCpyGp0=", "upload"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x33f55c8 @original_filename="Chrysanthemum.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[image]\"; filename=\"Chrysanthemum.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File...AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20141111-1960-9xj2rp>>}}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2.0ms

    TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):
      app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb:17:in `upload_params'
      app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb:7:in `create
```

Upload_controller:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @upload = Upload.new
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.create(upload_params)
    if @upload.save
      render json: { message: "success" }, :status => 200
    else
      render json: { error: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end
  end

   private
  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:image)
  end
end
```

Upload_model:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",:thumb => "100x100>" }

  validates_attachment  :image, 
        :presence => true,
        :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
        :size => { :less_than => 1.megabyte }
end
```

upload.html

```
<%= form_for(@upload, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
        <div class="fallback">
            <%= f.file_field :image %>
            <br>
            <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

Maybe, the problem is i don't use "strong_parameters" but when i add gem 'strong_parameters', it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix that :( Help me!

Comment: What does your schema for image look like? Are you sure you have all the right forms in the database for an image?

Comment: Why do you have a virtual attribute :image?